# How can I make a "list(range)" work when the quantity is not valid?

Tags: python

So, i'm new to python and trying to learn it, i've watched some clips on youtube and came up with this, but the last part to check in the quantity is or is not in the list range is not working....

```
print ("Hello, my name is Dave, welcome to our coffe shop!!")
name = input ("What is your name?\n")
print("Hello " + name + ", thank you for comming to our coffe shop!")
print ("What can i get you ?")
menu = str("caffe latte, " + "tea, " + "black coffe")
menu_choice = ["caffe latte","tea","black coffe"]
choice1 = input()   # anything 
print ("This is our menu:")
print (menu)
unavailable = True

# order loop for the coffe

while unavailable:
    order = input ()
    if order in menu_choice:
        unavailable = False
        print ("And how many " + order + " would you like?")
    else:
        print ("Sorry we dont have " + order + ", this is our menu :\n" + menu)
if order == "caffe latte":
    price = 13
elif order == "tea":
    price = 9
elif order == "black coffe":
    price = 15

#quantity loop

list(range(1, 10))
#here is the problem i'm having RN, the part with if not in in list is skipped
choice_number = True

while choice_number:
    quantity = input()
    total = price * int(quantity)
    if quantity not in {list} :
        choice_number = False
        if quantity == "1" :
            print ("Alright " + name, "that will be " + str(total) +"$,", "a", order + " comming at you!")
        elif quantity >= "2" :
            print ("Alright " + name, "that will be " + str(total) +"$,", quantity + " " + order + " comming at you!")
    else:
        print ("Quantity invalid, please select a number from 1 to 10.")
```

Comment: You're not assigning the list to a variable. `my_list = list(range(1, 10))` would allow you to use the list later under the variable name `my_list`

Comment: or just: `if quantity not in range(1, 11):`

Comment: Note that if you _did_ assign to a list like @Jeremy suggests, then you'd have to do `if quantity not in my_list`, not `if quantity not in {my_list}`, which tries to create a set containing `my_list`, which is not allowed since lists are mutable and therefore not hashable

Answer (score 0):

```
quantity = input("Enter Quantity")
total = price * int(quantity)
    if quantity not in range(1,10) :
        print ("Quantity invalid, please select a number from 1 to 10.")
    else:
        if quantity == "1":
            print("Alright " + name, "that will be " + str(total) + "$,", "a", order + " comming at you!")
        elif quantity >= "2":
            print("Alright " + name, "that will be " + str(total) + "$,", quantity + " " + order + " comming at you!")
```

I would recommend getting rid of the listed range and just doing it like this, also you don't need a while True loop its not really needed

Comment: I've tried this not working, i dont get the Quantity invalid answer if i put a quantity over 10.

Comment: updated have a look if that helps you , as the choice number = false cuts off the rest of the code.

Comment: Still not working, for the 1st input i get the correct print, but after that it not looping anymore, also not working for a correct input 1-10 range

Comment: wait why do you need the if statements in a while loop in the first place, you can get rid of that, try that i just updated it again :)

Answer (score 0):

Assign this `list(range(1, 10))` in a variable like `qty_lst = list(range(1, 10))`.

or you can simnply write:

`if quantity not in list(range(1, 10)):`

Answer (score 0):

```
if quantity < 1 or quantity > 10:
   # not in range
else:
   # in range
```

Dont use if ... in range(), i'm not sure about this, but i think that doing so, python will not know that the sequence is in order and will check your value against all the sequence.

If i'm wrong, let's say i learned something :D